# Random process on a sequence of rolls of an $n$-sided die

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, random-walks

Let $\ X:=X_{k\,n}\ $ be a random variable of a $n$-sided die where $\Pr(X=i)=\frac{1}{n}$ for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\},\ $ where $\ k\in\{1, 2, \ldots,n\}\ $ and $\ n\ $ are fixed. Let $t$ be a parameter that varies according to the outcome of each roll. Initially $t=1$ and we **stop** rolling the die when $t=0$.

Each time when the value $x$ taken by $X$ is less than or equal to $\ k\ $ we win $x$ dollars and we decrease $t$ by $1$. Each time when $x$ is larger than $k$, we lose $x$ dollars and we increase $t$ by adding $x-1$ to its current value. We have an unlimited amount of money.

**Question:** What is the minimum value of $\ k:= k(n)\ $ such that the expected number of dollars obtained (i.e., the difference between the total number of dollars won and the total number of dollars lost) is strictly larger than $0$?

Comment: Is "larger than" a strict inequality?

Comment: Yes @kodlu . The meaning basically is "When is convenient to play this game? (without loosing time)"  Edited.

Comment: I feel that the q. about Wald should be moved to a comment.

Comment: Is Wald's equation useful in this case?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, whenever we take $k < n-1$, the counter $t$ has positive drift and there is a positive probability that the game never terminates.  What do we mean by "total number of dollars won" in this case?

Comment: Wald does seem helpful because this is a random walk $S_m$ stopped at a stopping time $\tau$.  However to apply it, we need to have $E[\tau] < \infty$ and as I note above, in most cases we do not even have $\tau < \infty$ a.s.

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge for your comments. I see. Let $T$ be the random variable equal to total number of rolls (taking value $\tau\in[1,\infty]$), and let $D(r)~~ (:=D_{k,n}(r))$ be the total number of dollars won at round $r$. $D(r)<0$ means that we are loosing money at round $r$. Instead of asking for 
$\mathbb{E}[D(T)]$ as in the original problem version, would it be more meaningful to ask for 
$\mathbb{E}[\lim\sup_{r\to T}D(r)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\lim\inf_{r\to T}D(r)]$?

Comment: I was also wondering how does this problem change if, whenever $X\le k$, we decrease $t$ by $x+1$ (instead of by $1$), and the stopping condition is $t\le 0$? I guess in this case the "symmetry" of the problem could make it easier to solve.